# How to display two combobox columns in Datagrid from Dto with collections?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, combobox, datagrid

i need display two combobox columns in my datagrid.ItemsSource property is filling with ProductModel class.

```
public class ProductModel
{
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<decimal> Prices { get; set; }
    public decimal Cost { get; set; }
    public decimal Stock { get; set; }
    public List<string> Presentations { get; set; }
    public string  BarCode { get; set; }
}
```

XAML:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="dgProducts" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="343" Width="351" ItemsSource="{Binding ProductList}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
             SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedProduct}"  >
            <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseDoubleClick" >
                   <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding RowDobuleClickCommand}" />
                </i:EventTrigger>
            </i:Interaction.Triggers>
           <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Descripción" Binding="{Binding Name}" Width="200" />
                <DataGridComboBoxColumn Header="Precios"  Width="70"/>
                <DataGridComboBoxColumn Header="Presentaciónes" Width="70" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Disponible" Binding="{Binding Stock}" Width="100" />
            </DataGrid.Columns>

        </DataGrid>
```

How to bind property Prices and Presentations from same itemssource data grid or something like that. ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace below code:

```
 <DataGridComboBoxColumn Header="Precios"  Width="70"/>
 <DataGridComboBoxColumn Header="Presentaciónes" Width="70" />
```

With Following code:

```
    <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Precios"  Width="100" >
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Prices}">
                <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding}"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
            </ComboBox>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn>

    <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Presentaciónes"  Width="100" >
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Presentations}">
                <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding}"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
            </ComboBox>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn>
```